# sql trigger insert between two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers, insert

I have two database DB_OLD and DB_NEW and DB_OLD has a table like Documents. our bureau program saves information into Document table. I copy all information of Documents to DB_NEW's Documents2 table. I Want; The Officcers saves an information into DB_OLD'S Documents table, automatically the same record will save into DB_NEW's Documents2 table. For this situatin a wrote a trigger like this;

```
    USE [DB_OLD]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER SameRecord ON Documents AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF @@rowcount = 0 RETURN;
INSERT INTO DB_NEW.[DBO].Documents2(x,y,z) SELECT x,y,z FROM INSERTED
END;
```

But when executing the trigger officers records dont have been saved even DB_OLD's Documents table also DB_NEW's Documents2 table. whats worng?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to have a trigger access anything outside of its own database. If you can tolerate the (minimal) delay it imposes, I'd suggest that you introduce an intermediate step that isolates the original transaction from the activity that has to happen in another database - such as using a service broker queue.

Comment: i dont want to use DB_OLD'tables because at my new tables i have new columns and fields adding to old tables. the day, my new program will setup to all computers; the officers will enter new datas to old database. my wish; when the officers enter the data to db, the same ones will pass my database. so i use triggers. i dont have any idea on your solution Service Broker Queue??